# Hovered span displaying under image

Tags: html, css

So I have a list of 'things' people can earn with information about each one displayed like this.

<--div 1   a.img--> <--div 2   a.img--> <--div 3   a.img-->

<--div 4   a.img--> <--div 5   a.img--> <--div 6   a.img-->

When i hover over the a.img in div 1 the span that displays is underneath the img in div 4.

this is the css i have

```
a {
    cursor: default;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 1;
}

a:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background:#ffffff;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    color:#6c6c6c;
    max-width: 210px;
    padding:5px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking

Comment: What do you mean? Could you give some proper Html code?

Comment: Where is the image supposed to display? Please put this in a fiddle so people can test it. http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You should give `display: block` to `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Without some html code it is difficult to be sure, but I would guess that there are some unclosed tags in the source. But if I understand correctly, you have some boxes (images in your case), and you have some captions/text that you want to display at the bottom of the boxes when the user moves their mouse over them.

Below I will show how you can get this effect using only CSS. I will use divs that I float as the boxes. The basic html and css is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
}
.box h2 { text-align: center; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"><h2>Div 1</h2></div>
    <div class="box"><h2>Div 2</h2></div>
    <div class="box"><h2>Div 3</h2></div>
    <div class="box"><h2>Div 4</h2></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will show four yellow boxes with a header inside them. For the labels we add a simple `<span>` at the end of each div, as follows:

```
<div class="box"><h2>Div 1</h2><span>div 1 hover</span></div>
```

Then we add the following css to make them only visible when the user moves the mouse over the box:

```
.box span {
    display: none;
}

.box:hover span {
    display: inline;
}
```

Now the basic effect is present. Next is to get the hover text positioned correctly. Do do this we use absolute positioning for the `span` relative to the box. To do this we first add `position:relative` to the rule `.box { /* ... */ }`. Now we add `position:absolute` to `.box:hover span { /*...*/ }`. Since the box has relative position, the position of the absolutely positioned `span` will be relative to the box.

Now we can position the `span` using the attributes `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` as follows:

```
.box span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This will place the bottom of the `span` element at the bottom of the box, and resize it so that it goes from left to right. The text itself is centered horizontally centered. If you now move the mouse over any of the boxes, the text will display at the bottom of each box.

For completeness, here is the full example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin: 10px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .box h2 { text-align: center; }

    .box span {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .box:hover span {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"><h2>Div 1</h2><span>div 1 hover</span></div>
    <div class="box"><h2>Div 2</h2><span>div 2 hover</span></div>
    <div class="box"><h2>Div 3</h2><span>div 3 hover</span></div>
    <div class="box"><h2>Div 4</h2><span>div 4 hover</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```